# How to divide an image into ''n'' different polygons in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am new to python and am trying to divide an image into 'n' different polygon using python. My target is to convert an image into n random polygon shaped images. I tried Voronoi algorithm but its kind of messy. I would really appreciate any help. Any other segmentation method etc.

My previous Code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

img = plt.imread("abc.jpg")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img)

def points(radius,rangeX,rangeY,qty):
    deltas = set()
    for x in range(-radius, radius+1):
        for y in range(-radius, radius+1):
            if x*x + y*y <= radius*radius:
                deltas.add((x,y))

    randPoints = []
    excluded = set()
    i = 0
    while i<qty:
        x = random.randrange(*rangeX)
        y = random.randrange(*rangeY)
        if (x,y) in excluded: continue
        randPoints.append((x,y))
        i += 1
        excluded.update((x+dx, y+dy) for (dx,dy) in deltas)
    return randPoints



def plot1(randPoints,fig):
    points = np.array(randPoints)
    vor = Voronoi(points)
    print vor.vertices
    voronoi_plot_2d(vor,ax = fig.gca())
    #plt.savefig('abc.png')
    plt.show()
    
radius = 20
rangeX = (0, 960)
rangeY = (0, 480)
qty = 9

points = points(radius, rangeX, rangeY, qty)
plot1(points,fig)
```

My Input:
[image]

My output:
[image]

This is for n = 9 I would appreciate any help I can get.